# What is the best way to read the Rails session secret?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I would like to access the Rails session secret programmatically (I am using it to generate a sign-on token).

Here's what I've come up with:

```
ActionController::Base.session.first[:secret]
```

This returns the session secret. However, every time you call ActionController::Base.session it adds another entry to an array so you end up with something like this:

```
[{:session_key=>"_new_app_session", :secret=>"totally-secret-you-guys"}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

This strikes me as being no good.

Is there a better way to access the session secret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActionController::Base.session_options_for(request,params[:action])[:secret]
```

Answer (score 12):

For Rails4

```
Rails.configuration.secret_token
Rails.configuration.secret_key_base
```

For Rails3

```
Rails.configuration.secret_token
```

But if for Rails2.x, like Don Parish mentioned

```
ActionController::Base.session_options[:secret]
```

Comment: I'm getting nil for both. This isn't normal, is it? I have introduced a `config/secrets.yml` file a few days ago, maybe it isn't read?

Comment: The secrets added to that file are accessible via `Rails.application.secrets`.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, Jake.

Since the secret doesn't change based on the request or the action, this also works:

```
ActionController::Base.session_options_for(nil,nil)[:secret]
```

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 2.3, I've used:

```
ActionController::Base.session_options[:secret]
```

Comment: Cool, that looks cleaner. I'll have to update our code when we upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 3, Rails.configuration is same to Rails.application.config, so Rails.configuration.secret_token acts just as what choonkeat provided.